Prove cardinality of R2 without creating a map to R1
I think we can prove $|\mathbb{R}^2|=\aleph_1$, by creating a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$. But this map is difficult to construct. Is there any easier way to show $|\mathbb{R}^2|=\aleph_1$?

It is consistent that $\operatorname{card} \Bbb R>\aleph_1$. If you want a symbol that denotes the cardinality of $\Bbb R$, use $\mathfrak c$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$ or $\beth_1$.

What do you mean precisely by "prove $|\mathbb{R}^2|=\aleph_1$"?

One proves ${\bf R}^2$ has the cardinality of the continuum by displaying a bijection between ${\bf R}^2$ and a set known to have the cardinality of the continuum (such as $\bf R$). What other type of proof do you have in mind? What other type could there be?

As the others have hinted, proving that the cardinality is $\aleph_1$ is not simple or even possible.  $\aleph_1$ is the next largest cardinal after $\aleph_0$.  Whether this is the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is the Continuum Hypothesis.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis

Let $2$ denote the set $\{0,1\}$, and $Y^X$ denote the set of maps $X\to Y$.
$$\begin{align}|\Bbb R^2|&=|(2^{\Bbb N})^2|\\&=|2^{\Bbb N\times2}|\\&=|2^{\Bbb N}|\\&=|\Bbb R|.\end{align}$$
The central argument,
$$|(A^B)^C|=|A^{B\times C}|,$$
is proved for instance here.

Maybe we can apply Schröder-Bernstein Theorem to make it "slightly" easier:

Theorem (Schröder-Bernstein): If $|A|\leq|B|$ and $|B|\leq|A|$, then $|A|=|B|$.

Note that $|A|\leq |B|$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists$ injection $A\rightarrow B$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists$ surjection $B\rightarrow A$. So in order to show $|A|=|B|$ we only need, instead of a bijection, one of the followings:

An injection $A\rightarrow B$ and a surjection $A\rightarrow B$.
An injection $B\rightarrow A$ and a surjection $B\rightarrow A$.
Two injections $A\rightarrow B$ and $B\rightarrow A$.
Two surjections $A\rightarrow B$ and $B\rightarrow A$.

The projection $(x,y)\mapsto x$ is clearly a surjection $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. An injection $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, sadly however, still requires some technique you may have encountered:

For $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, write the decimals
$$x=\pm\overline{x_nx_{n-1}\cdots x_1x_0.x_{-1}x_{-2}\cdots}$$
$$y=\pm\overline{y_ny_{n-1}\cdots y_1y_0.y_{-1}y_{-2}\cdots}$$
Here we add a least number of $0$'s before the decimal of $x$ or $y$ so that they have the same number of digits before the decimal dot. We also require that decimal representations cannot end in a series of $9$'s.
Now we define $f(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}$ to be
$$\overline{ax_ny_nx_{n-1}y_{n-1}\cdots x_1y_1x_0y_0.x_{-1}y_{-1}x_{-2}y_{-2}\cdots}$$
where
$$a=\begin{cases}1,\quad x\geq 0, y\geq 0,\\
2,\quad x\geq 0,y<0,\\
3,\quad x<0,y\geq 0,\\
4,\quad x<0,y<0.\end{cases}$$

It is easy to show $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is an injection since you can reconstruct $x$ and $y$ from the decimal representation of $f(x,y)$. Just read every digit.

Nitpick: $|A|\leq |B|$ if and only if there exists a surjection $B\to A$ or $A = \varnothing$. Note that if $A = \varnothing$ and $B\neq \varnothing$, then $|A|\leq |B|$, but is no function $B\to A$ at all.
